# Read table with replacment tabs by some character during reading

Tags: r, gsub

unfortunaly it's me again. I'd like to ask you, is it possible to read in r one-column table (one header) which has multiple values in rows separated by `\t` and combine them together... I'ts a bit difficult to explain so I'll provide and example.

Let's have some data in file .txt:

```
FILE_HEADER
AB  DF  12A
GG  ER
FF
FOO BAR FOO
```

I cant read it directly into R - `more columns than column names` which is obvious. However is it possible to read it and reshape it into something like this:

```
FILE_HEADER
AB;DF;12A
GG;ER
FF
FOO;BAR;FOO
```

Comment: just use `read.csv` and then replace the spaces with semicolons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in your data using `readLines` and then substitute the `\t`:

```
data_vect <- readLines("yourFile.txt")
data_vect <- gsub("\t",";",data_vect)
data_df <- data.frame(data_vect[-1], stringsAsFactors = F)
names(data_df) <- data_vect[1]

data_df
#  FILE_HEADER
#1   AB;DF;12A
#2       GG;ER
#3          FF
#4 FOO;BAR;FOO
```